# Rails actionmailer sending emails for commentable model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer, acts-as-commentable

I'm trying to send emails through my actionmailer to the commentable owners' email after another user writes them a comment but I keep getting an error. Can someone help me out with this? Thanks in advance.

**comment_mailer.rb**

```
def email_notification(member, comment)
    @member = commentable.member
    @sender = comment.member
    mail to: commentable.member.email, subject: "#{comment.member.full_name} (#{comment.member.user_name}) has left you a comment"
end
```

**comment.rb**

```
belongs_to :member
belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
attr_accessible :content

after_create :send_email

def send_email
    CommentMailer.email_notification(member, comment).deliver
end
```

**error**

```
undefined local variable or method `comment' for #<Comment:0x51c2ad8>

app/models/comment.rb:18:in `send_email'
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:20:in `block in create'
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:19:in `create'
```

**comments_controller**

```
before_filter :authenticate_member!
before_filter :load_commentable
before_filter :find_member

def index
    redirect_to root_path
end

def new
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new
end

def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(params[:comment])
    @comments = @commentable.comments.order('created_at desc').page(params[:page]).per_page(15)
    @comment.member = current_member
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to :back }
        format.json
        format.js
      else
        format.html { redirect_to :back }
        format.json
        format.js
      end
    end 
end

def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.member == current_member || @commentable.member == current_member
        @comment.destroy
        format.html { redirect_to :back }
        format.json
        format.js
      else
       format.html { redirect_to :back, alert: 'You can\'t delete this comment.' }
       format.json
       format.js
      end
    end 
end

private

def load_commentable
    klass = [Status, Medium, Project, Event, Listing].detect { |c| params["#{c.name.underscore}_id"] }
    @commentable = klass.find(params["#{klass.name.underscore}_id"])
end

def find_member
    @member = Member.find_by_user_name(params[:user_name])
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You error is in the `send_email` method. There is no local variable called `comment`. You are already inside an instance of comment, the instance you want to send an email about. So you want to use the keyword `self` instead.

Change this:

```
def send_email
  CommentMailer.email_notification(member, comment).deliver
end
```

To this:

```
def send_email
  CommentMailer.email_notification(member, self).deliver
end
```

`self` refers to the current instance of comment, which you want to use for your mailer.